# MapInfo incorrectly counting lines intersecting a buffer

Tags: mapinfo, buffer, intersection

I made a buffer for all objects on start and end nodes of polylines then disaggregated them. I then used update table to derive the number of lines intersecting:

[image]

However this appears to be incorrect as a result of 8 is returned for the following buffer, when there are only 6 polylines:

[image]

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that there are no duplicate polylines lying underneath the 6 polylines that you can see and that you haven't accidentally inserted any other objects into the table. A good way to do this is to do a boundary select on one of the buffers that is returning the wrong count and browse the results. Then select each record in turn in the browser window and use the 'Zoom to selection' functionality in the map window to find each selected object. That should allow you to find out where the extra objects are coming from.